# Password counting: number of $8$-character alphanumeric passwords in which at least two characters are digits

Tags: combinatorics

I had an exam yesterday and wanted to confirm if I am correct, one of the questions was:
Suppose there is a string that has 8 characters composed of alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-10) how many combinations are there were there are at least 2 characters that only contain numbers?

I calculated that there are 36 characters (26 letters and 10 numbers) and as the length of the string is 8, $36^8$combinations, if I wanted to calculate how many of this combinations contain at least one number: $36^8-(36-26)^8$ so to calculate the answer for at least two numbers is it correct to state that the formula is: $36^8-(10^8+10^8)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider binomial expansion of
$$(26+10)^8=\sum\limits_{k=0}^8 {8\choose k}\,10^k\, 26^{8-k}$$ where each term corresponds to number of passwords with exactly $k$ numbers and $8-k$ letters.
So your answer will be (as mentioned in the [Alex's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3756026)) $$36^8-26^8-{8\choose 1}\cdot 10\cdot 26^7.$$

Answer (score 5):

If you mean 'number of strings such that there are numbers in two or more positions':

1)Total:$36^8$

2)No numbers at all:$26^8$

3)Exactly one number: $8 \cdot 10 \cdot 26^7$

Now subtract 2) and 3) from 1)